# Findbugs with Gradle plugin doesn't work in Java 9

Tags: java, findbugs, java-9

I am migrating my project (multi project in `Gradle`) from Java 8 to Java 9 (without using modules so far). I use Gradle 4.3 and Findbugs Gradle plugin - I have `apply plugin: 'findbugs'` in my `gradle.build` file. In dependencies I have

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'
compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'annotations', version: '3.0.1'
```

Previously, with `java 8` (`open-jdk`) everything worked normally, but when I used `java 9` (`oracle - build 9.0.1+11`), I got the following exception after executing `gradle check` (`com.example.custom.MyClass` is a class from my codebase):
    The following errors occurred during analysis:

```
Error scanning com/example/custom/MyClass for referenced classes
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
  At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.<init>(FBClassReader.java:35)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:48)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:262)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:75)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:262)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:774)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
  At org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.findbugs.FindBugsExecuter.runFindbugs(FindBugsExecuter.java:39)
  At java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  At java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  At java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  At java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
  At org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:100)
  At org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.runThenStop(WorkerAction.java:83)
  At java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  At java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  At java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  At java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
  At org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
  At org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
  At org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:146)
  At org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:128)
  At org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
  At org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  At org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  At java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  At java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  At org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  At java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

This appears for every class from my gradle project (and also for every class which Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel generator generated).
I guess this will be related to jigsaw modules. However I don't declare any `module-info.java`, so I guess an automatic module is created for the whole codebase and everything is accessible from anywhere.

Comment: "I guess this will be related to jigsaw modules" - no, this is nothing to do with modules. From the stack trace, it seems that Findbugs is using ASM and ASM is throwing IllegalArgumentException, probably because it's an old version of ASM that doesn't understand v53.0 class files. A notice on the Findbugs project on github asks to report issues to Spotbugs instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though findbugs [Java9 support](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs/issues/105) doesn't look moving ahead even gradually. And there are more [posts](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/720) about it which eventually suggests using [spotbugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs) instead.

```
compile 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs:3.1.0'
```

You shall find this [migration guide](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) useful for the same.

---

<strike>You might though just want to give a try to override the ASM version to 6.0 in your project's build using:</strike>

```
compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0'
```

Comment: Findbugs has a dependency to `asm-commons` and `asm-debug-all`. I added `compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:6.0'` and `compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:6.0_BETA'`
and after I check dependencies I still see
`\--- com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.1
     +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.2
     +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.2
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.2
     |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.2`

It still doesn't work. Probably better solution will be to migrate to `spotbugs` as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @fxmasa ya that shall be the way as I would guess primarily. Or as one of the comments  on those github issues read is to pull the java 9 related branch and update stuff yourself to make use of it.